# Ignition coil HV power supply damage?

Tags: capacitor, transformer, high-voltage

I recently built a HV power supply, as per the [link](https://www.instructables.com/id/Variable-voltage-ignition-coil-power-supply/) (using a pencil ignition coil).  However, I used a capacitor of around 5nf, which meant the supply did not work.  The capacitor reduced the amps too much, and I did not get a plasma stream as a result.  My questions are,

would this have damaged the ignition coil in any way?

Maybe the open secondary which resulted from no plasma stream caused internal carbon tracing?

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a more dangerous circuit. There is no isolation and this is very likely to kill you if misused. Get yourself an isolation transformer (110-110) or even a 110-220 step-up/down transformer.

Answer (score 1):

This circuit depends on the quirks of the two-wire lighting dimmer you use. Some will will not work into the 'interesting' load, and most will not work below some minimum load.

You can modify the circuit to be more robust (and to test the dimmer!) by first wiring the dimmer in series with a suitably sized filament bulb. This provides a 'tame' load, and importantly provides a visual indication of whether it's working or not.

Now you can put your ignition coil + series capacitor combination across the dimmer terminals (or the lamp terminals, but the dimmer terminals reduce emission to the house wiring, a little).

**SAFETY**

Do follow the instructables' safety advice, and to Jack's in comments (use an isolation transformer). Mains voltage is made somewhat less dangerous by the fact that it won't jump through dry clothing. However, what you've built is an arc starter, the iggy-coil output will jump half an inch through air or clothing, and that arc could then connect you to mains. Several people have died in this way, with an un-isolated mains-powered high voltage generator connecting them accidentally to mains.

Comment: So would it have damaged the coil?

Comment: probably not, the low value capacitor will under-power it, so protect it. You could try testing the iggy coil in the way it's meant to be used. Connect it to a 12v battery, and then break the connection, less than 12v will work as well. Be kind to the secondary and its insulation before you do this, make a 5mm or less spark gap between the HT terminal and the can. Not only do you have a reasonable gap to see the spark, but it also keeps the secondary voltage down. No gap means it could break over internally if you drive it hard enough.

Comment: Alright, thanks.  I worked out the amps would have been around 0.0003 amps (240v), as opposed to the recommended minimum of 0.3 amps.  It ran for around a minute and a half with no spark.  Do you think that damaged it?

Comment: which bit of 'probably not, try testing it' don't you understand?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I just don’t have the coil any more